# How to enable switch user rights in RHEL Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, users, su

I am not an UNIX/Linux administrator.  I got a requirement and I am trying to find a solution for the same.  In my team, I got few developers who got their employee id.  We want to allow the developers to login the Linux machine via putty with their own employee id and then switch to a local user 'localuser'.

We already configured our corporate AD for the developer to login with their employee id.  Also we already got a local user 'localuser' created with blank password.  After they login with their employee id, they do 'su -l localuser' to switch to local user.  But they get access denied error.

How can I enable 'su' access? What configuration should I have to do and where?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "no password" mean? Blank? Account disabled?

Comment: @Panki i mean blank password.